# Read HTML data in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to load soccer data from HTMl into R-studio, to be able to analyze it.
However, I get the following error when I use the code I created

Error in read_html("https://nl.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eredivisie/20202021/regular-season/r57990/") :
could not find function "read_html"

**Code:**

```
ereTable <- read_html("https://nl.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eredivisie/20202021/regular-season/r57990/")
```

**Website**
https://nl.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eredivisie/20202021/regular-season/r57990/

**Other code to make the table**

```
tblEre <- ereTable %>%

  html_node(css = "table#page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_league_table_1_table.leaguetable.sortable.table.detailed-table") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE, header = FALSE) %>% 
  
  slice(1:19) %>%
  slice(-1:-1) %>%
  
  select(-c("X2", "X12", "X13", "X14")) %>%
  
  setNames(c("Plaats", "Team", "Gespeeld", "Winst", "Gelijk", "Verlies", "Voor", "Tegen", "DoelSaldo", "Punten"))

tblEre
```

Probably I overlook something, which makes it impossible to load the data. Can somebody help me make sure I get this data loaded into a new markdown project?

Comment: First guess: You forgot to load the packages, e.g. read_html is a function from xml2.

Comment: I use this liberarys

Comment: ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
```

Comment: Hm. `rvest` should be fine as it also attaches `xml2` in the background. What I would do: 1. Restart R. Ctrl + Alt + F10 (on Windows). Try again. 2. Make s simple script with just 2 lines. library(rvest) and `ereTable <- read_html ....` Check wether this works.

Comment: Thx, i made this ```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://nl.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eredivisie/20202021/regular-season/r57990/"
url %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
   html_table()
``` , But If i runs it I get the matches of the site and not the competition table https://nl.soccerway.com/national/netherlands/eredivisie/20202021/regular-season/r57990/

Comment: Okay. At least now it works. I had a look at the website. `html_nodes("table")` returns a list with four tables, The macthes are the first, the league table the second. Hence, try `.[[2]] %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)` (I added fill = TRUE as I got an error. I guess the table is messed up. So you probably have do some manual cleaning).

Comment: Ik dacht er aan om een andere site te proberen maar dan krijg ik ,  Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds   Site: https://www.voetbal.nl/team/T515108858/stand